# Problem indexing "SETI@home"

Tags: symbols, indexing

Entered \index{SETI@home}. It (TexShop) printed "home" only - at the right place for "SETI..". How do I tell makeindex the "@" is a text to be included?

Comment: Please read up on how `\index` is to be used in latex. `@` is a reserved char in indexes (then the first part will be used for sorting and the latter as the actual typed in the output). Similarly `!` and `|` are also special chars in `\index`. You can escape the special char using `"`, so use `\index{SETI"@HOME}`

Comment: There are some explanations here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Indexing

Answer (score 2):

by default `@` is the `actual` character used to separate (when needed) a typeset form from the string used for index sorting. As such it can be preceded by the `quote` character, which by default is `"`  so

```
\index{SETI"@HOME}
```

If you have a lot of such things you can change the characters in a style specified using `makeindex -s mystyle.ist`.

For example the `base` latex release has a `gind.ist` to match the `doc` package which is designed for indexing latex code, which uses

```
actual '='
quote '!'
```

so `@` is replaced by `=` and `"` by `!` so `@` is a normal character and

```
\index{SETI@HOME}
```

would work as intended

Comment: Thank you! - I could not find the " thing documented.

Comment: `texdoc ind`  https://texdoc.org/serve/ind.pdf/0